Как в telegram боте отредактировать сообщение и вместо него поставить 2 картинки c кнопками и подпись?
У меня бот - TeleBot. Есть два файла inf_spr_gtav_1.jpg , inf_spr_gtav_2.jpg и нужно их отправить с текстом и inline кнопками при этом изменить предыдущее сообщение. Ну если это не возможно, то как просто изменить с одной картинкой кнопками и текстом?
with [telebot.types.InputMediaPhoto(open('inf_spr_gtav_1.jpg', 'rb')), telebot.types.InputMediaPhoto(open('inf_spr_gtav_2.jpg', 'rb'))] as file:
 photo = types.InputMediaPhoto(file)
bot.edit_message_media(chat_id=msg_chat_id, message_id=msg_id, media=photo)

